# How to configure and build sqlcipher for android?

Tags: android, c++, sqlite, sqlcipher

I would like to use sqlcipher in my android project. 
I've used an sql wrapper called Kompex SQLite Wrapper which includes the
**sqlite3.h**
**sqlite3ext.h**
**shell.c**
**sqlite3.c**
files in it.
It is not neccessary for me to use the sqlite database from java code (actually I want to avoid that), because I have all the logic in c++ for the backend. I still want to use the Kompex SQLite Wrapper but I am planning to replace the files mentioned above to "support" database encryption.
*Basically I need an amalgamation of the sqlcipher source code, so I can replace the files.*
I've tried to download the sqlcipher and run configure (which does this).
It creates the files I mentioned but after I copied them to the right place I can't compile them.
For me it would be better to have these source files after amalgamation proccess and compile them with my source files instead of linking against an sqlcipher library because it makes easier to compile these files for desktop also.
(I am using the same backend logic on desktop also.)
**Any suggestion where can I get the amalgamated source files of sqlcipher just like Kompex SQLite Wrapper has?**
Thanks.

Comment: Any solution yet?